# Java delay function

Tags: java, android, multithreading, function, delay

BuzzerControl function is a function that sounds buzzer. I want this function to blink once every three seconds. What should I do? I tried sleep function but it doesn't work.

```
While(true){
 BuzData=1;
 BuzzerControl(BuzData);
}
```

Comment: In which thread you want this functionality either on UI thread or background thread ?

Comment: Probably UI thread. It is a process that is executed by pressing Button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, we need a `Handler` that starts the Runnable after 3000ms i.e 3seconds

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 3000);
```

And we also need the Runnable for the Handler

```
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      /* do what you need to do */
      foobar();
      /* and here comes the "trick" */
      handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
   }
```

> Note:There’s also another advantage of this solution: You don’t have
>   to create new Timer(Task)s all the time and can reuse the one Handler
>   and Runnable.